# How can I build a relation between columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, last.fm, knowledge-graph

I have a data frame from the LASTFM dataset with columns:
**user_id | friend_id** like so:

```
uid | fid
346 | 23
355 | 48
```

and I would like to have a relation between users as a third columns (kind of an adjacency vector), such as:

```
uid1 | uid2 | friends
23   | 48   | 0
23   | 56   | 0
23   | ..   | 0
23   | 346  | 1
48   | 23   | 0
48   | 56   | 0
48   | ..   | 0
48   | 346  | 0
48   | 355  | 1
23   | ..   | 0
23   | 346  | 1
346  | 23   | 1
```

I have tried working with *merge, join, lambda* but have so far been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: merge after assign a key equal to one

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S. As I understood it, I did

```uniques_df = pd.DataFrame(df['fid'].unique(), columns=['uid'])
uniques_df['rel'] = ones['rel'] # only 1s
df2 = df.merge(uniques_df, on='uid', how='outer', suffixes=('', '2'))
df2.head()```

I had tried something similar before, but I also have to have the zeros where fields are not related and I have to have all combinations of uids (like a cross product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy here is two step. First create the UID cross product dataset, then attach the friends indicator:

Create the UID cross product by first taking the union of pairs from original dataset, along with their inverses. We'll create an intermediate dataset, `friends`, which we'll use later in the process to indicate which UIDs are friends:

```
pairs = df.rename(columns={'uid': 'uid1', 'fid': 'uid2'})
friends = pd.concat([pairs, pairs.rename(columns={'uid1': 'uid2', 'uid2':'uid1'})])
uids = friends.uid1.drop_duplicates().to_frame(name='uid')

   uid
0  346
1  355
0   23
1   48
```

Then, append a dummy merge key to allow a cross product merge:

```
uids['dummy_key'] = 1
uids = uids.merge(uids, on='dummy_key', suffixes=('1', '2'))[['uid1', 'uid2']]

    uid1  uid2
0    346   346
1    346   355
2    346    23
3    346    48
4    355   346
5    355   355
...
```

Now, we merge on the friends dataset, attaching an indicator column, to start our adjacency list:

```
adj = uids.merge(friends, on=['uid1', 'uid2'], how='left', indicator=True)

    uid1  uid2     _merge
0    346   346  left_only
1    346   355  left_only
2    346    23       both
3    346    48  left_only
4    355   346  left_only
5    355   355  left_only
...
```

Finally, we code the `_merge` indicator into the `friend` column:

```
adj['friends'] = adj.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['_merge'] == 'both' else 0, axis=1)
adj = adj[['uid1', 'uid2', 'friends']]

    uid1  uid2  friends
0    346   346        0
1    346   355        0
2    346    23        1
3    346    48        0
4    355   346        0
5    355   355        0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Dave
It works and I can understand it!
The only minor problem is that the Collab RAM is not enough for the line ```uids = uids.merge(uids, on='dummy_key', suffixes=('1', '2'))[['uid1', 'uid2']]``` . But that I can deal with.
Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help! A cross product like this is very expensive. Look into using a numpy sparse matrix if you want an adjacency matrix: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: Thanks once more. I will!